# Is it possible to send image or files through url_launcher in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Text can be send through url_launcher package but is it supports images or files to send it to other apps install in device?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use url_launcher package to send file/images. However, this can be done with [share_plus](https://share_plus:%20%5E3.0.4) plugin. It supports files/images/texts etc, you can read more about it in documentation.

Comment: not working in my case